# Generate pdf with unicode characters

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, fonts, reportlab

I using python + reportlab for generating pdf. But here is some problem with unicode fonts.

I need english, european and asian languages in my pdf.

But I can't find any free unicode fonts, that working with all languages.

Where is I can find it?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: What is your question? The only problem I can see based on what you've shown us is that FreeSerif does not implement all Unicode characters, which is really a support issue for the maintainers of that font.

Comment: I second G Gordon.  If you are trying to get certain characters you need to have a font with glyphs that exists.  If the glyph doesn't exists in unicode, then yes, it's going to show up in ReportLab as missing.  Do you have a reason to believe that hieroglyphics should be present in the FreeSerif font?  If you are on *Nix you might want to open the font using something like FontForge and check to see what that unicode->glyph mapping is.  If it's not there you need a different font (or be bold enough to try and make your own).

Comment: @Nascent_Notes can you suggest me free unicode font with hieroglyphics characters and with other unicode symbols. GNU font looks really bad...

Comment: hieroglyphics = ancient Egyptian hieroglyphics?  Is there any other kind?  I have no idea... can you be more specific - I pretty much only deal with English and don't consider myself a linguist.

Comment: @Nascent_Notes I'm talking about japanese and chinese characters. I need english, european and asian languages in my pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:

- http://archive09.linux.com/feature/52756
- http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=CharisSILfont
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_Unicode_typefaces

The short answer, based on the comments on your original question, is that you need a new font.  Find a font that has all the glyphs that you want, then you will need to embed that font in the PDF document.

If you can't finding something in the links provided, let me know and I'll look more closely for you, but I suspect that you just need to poke around till you find the font that has all the glyphs you want.  Short of testing the font on a set of known unicode characters to make sure you are getting the desirable font/output you want, you could also use a program like "FontForge" (as I previously suggested in a comment) to poke around to see what glyphs are mapped (and which aren't).